# Table View not returning data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm a student iOS dev, and I'm trying to control a tableview in a collection view cell that is returning 3 (or more) tableviews so I can have multiple tableviews. I believe I implemented everything right but no data is returned to the individual tableviews I have set the reuseidentifiers in the prototype cells in the tableview, and also the delegate and datasource are set to the VC.

```
var tableView1: UITableView?
var tableview2: UITableView?


    // MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    if tableView == tableView1 {

        return 2;

    } else if tableView == tableview2 {

        return 3
    }
    return 0;

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if tableView == tableView1 {
        return 2;

    } else if tableView == tableview2 {

        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if tableView == tableView1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("testcell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    } else if tableView == tableview2 {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("testcell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if tableView == tableView1 {

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Homeroom"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "8:15 AM - 9:00 AM"
    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    } else if tableView == tableview2 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Test Table 2 "
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "1:30 PM - 2:30 PM"
        cell.selectionStyle = .None

    }

    return cell

}


//**Center collection cells in the middle**

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let sideInset = (collectionView.frame.size.width - 650) / 2
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: sideInset, bottom: 0, right: sideInset)
}

}

//Card Scrolling datasource 

extension SAHomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

    //Number of cards on home screen
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cardcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure collection view cell

    return cell
}
```

Here is my project editor to be clearer.

[image]

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that one of your if cases is always going to be true, even if you do know.  You need to return something in the case where both `tableView == tableView1` and `tableView == tableview2` are false, or change the second `else if ...` to just be an `else`

Comment: do you mean multiple table view cells instead of tableviews?

Comment: No not cells, I'm returning 2 collection view cells right now that represent 2 table views that will present different data

Comment: why do you need tableview inside collection view? If you want to display data you can do so by creating labels inside collections view as well. Is there a specific reason for creating tableView inside Collection View ?

Comment: Share us a sample project.So,we can look into it.Your code didn't show any detail at all.May be you are missing something at Storyboard.

Comment: @MeetShah it has to be a table view because that is my design here is a concept to better understand [Concept](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjt2nmdrc1jc5y3/Home_Page%402x.png?dl=0)

Comment: @6245Htarwara I can invite you to my repo on bitbucket, do you have a username?

Comment: @Hightower98 i have added few links which consists of example project and its explanation, check after EDIT

Comment: Here is my github profile : https://github.com/htarwara6245. I do have repo on bitbucket.But,i can't use it.It's private.

Comment: @6245Htarwara I added you as a collaborator on my temporary repo on github for my project. Thanks for your help up to this point!

Comment: I only saw login view at your project.No sign of tableview or collection view.

Comment: @6245Htarwara the collectionview and table view are in the home-tableview-fix branch not in the master in the SAHomeViewController.swift file

Comment: I still don't see why you want to use collection view.If you want to show two list at your home view,you can use two table view at the home view side by side.May I know why?

Comment: @6245Htarwara Becasue I will be using more than 2 table views in the future. I'm returning 2 right now to debug this issue and once the solution is found I will return more tableviews. And I trying my best to stay close to my design as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide default return value in both the functions. Because compiler checking that the functions required `Int` value should be returned and in these functions if any condition doesn't matched it will not return anything.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    if tableView == tableView1 {            
        return 2;            
    }
    else if tableView == tableview2
    {            
        return 3;
    }
    return 0; // here
}  

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if tableView == tableView1 {
        return 2;            
    } else if tableView == tableview2 {            
        return 1;
    }
    return 0; // here
}
```